# PHP search for student ID and last name

Tags: php

I have an assignment that has a form that takes ID and Last name as inputs. I want to take both the ID and Last Name and match it with the text file. If it matches, show that student in a table. If it doesn't match, echo that the student isn't found. So far, I got almost everything done, but everytime I search a student that exists, the student that isn't found is echoed.

Here is the link to my form: http://hills.ccsf.edu/~ryan/a7p1.php

Here is the class of students that you can get the ID and Last name from. The first column is the Student ID and the second column is the Last Name: http://fog.ccsf.edu/~tboegel/showclass.php

Here is the code:

```
<?php                                                                                                                      

$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];                                                                                               
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

function DisplayRow($ID) {                                                                                                 
    print "<tr>\n";
    $parts = split(":", $ID);                                                                                              
    for($i=0; $i <=7; $i++) {                                                                                              
    print "<td>$parts[$i]</td>\n";                                                                                     
    }
    print "</tr>\n";                                                                                                       
}

$handle = fopen("class.txt", "r");                                                                                         
$line = fgets($handle);
while(!feof($handle)) {                                                                                                    
    $part = explode(":", $line);                                                                                           
    if($id == $part[0] && $lname == $part[1]) {                                                                            
        echo "<table border='1' width='95%'>                  
        <tr>                                                                                                               
          <th>Student ID</th>                                                                                                
          <th>Student Last Name</th>                                                                                         
          <th>Student First Name</th>
          <th>Midterm 1</th>                                                                                                 
          <th>Midterm 2</th>
          <th>Midterm 3</th>
          <th>Final Exam</th>                                                                                                
          <th>Letter Grade</th>
        </tr>";
        DisplayRow($line);
    } else {
        print "The person you are trying to search for does not exist";
        die;
    }
    $line = fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
print "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: What does the file format look like ?? `Why not use a database` ??

Comment: It's my assignment for class, and we're not into databases yet

Comment: Don't add it has a comment .. has it to pastbin.com and just put the link here

Comment: I'll look into it byt why don't you want to use a Database ??

Comment: one could use regexp but i dont think you are not into this too :p

Comment: ChaosClown, thats next week :).  Baba, we're not into databases yet

Comment: @Baba: please read the homework tag wiki

Comment: @Mat just saw that now `This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. But don't remove it without looking at the question to see if it needs cleanup. Please see this question on Meta for more information.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the while seaches till it finds something then it breaks...
if the eof is reached it will trigger an error

```
<?php                                                                                                                      

$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

function DisplayRow($ID) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    $parts = split(":", $ID);
    for($i=0; $i <=7; $i++) {
        print "<td>$parts[$i]</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
$found = false;
$handle = fopen("class.txt", "r");
$line = fgets($handle);
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $part = explode(":", $line);
    if($id == $part[0] AND $lname == $part[1]) {
     echo "<table border='1' width='95%'>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Student Last Name</th>
            <th>Student First Name</th>
            <th>Midterm 1</th>
            <th>Midterm 2</th>
            <th>Midterm 3</th>
            <th>Final Exam</th>
            <th>Letter Grade</th>
        </tr>";

        DisplayRow($line);

        echo "</table>";
        $found = true;
        break; //no need to go further already found the data
    }
    $line = fgets($handle);
}
if($found == false) {
    echo "The person you are trying to search for does not exist";
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours worked perfect :), but did you mean if($found == false) { echo "...." }

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is simple ..... you are terminating the loop prematurely

```
else {
        print "The person you are trying to search for does not exist"; //??
        die;
    }    ^--------------- This your issue (Remove)
```

**Better Still** Use a database like `SQLite` or `MySQL`

Please also note that `split` is depreciated ,i'll advice to use `explode` instead

```
$parts = split(":", $ID);  
           ^-------------  Change to explode
```

Comment: If I don't use die, it prints that string like a more than 5 times because it searches it line by line i think

Comment: sqlite it not a good choice its not supported in all browsers

Comment: @ChaosClown explain your self better

Comment: forget about it its not the right place to discuss this issue, its a good thing but not good supported

Comment: @Raymond Yan You are showing the "not found"-message too early (each time
the person is not found).
Set a flag if the person is found, and print the error message
if the flag is still not set when you exit the loop.

Comment: @Raymond Yan that is why i added `??`  this are basic corrections you can use a boolean instead of printing .. i just don't like the fact that you are using a flat file for such kind of task .... you would face issues would locking and fragmentation later

Comment: @Baba I told you two times that this is for a class assignment. I'm not into a database yet. I know databases are easier to work with. If I could switch to databases, I would

Comment: @Raymond Yan Oh ok .. next time had homework tag to the question .... If need a better implementation let me know .....

Comment: @Baba Ok thats good to know. I'm still new to PHP and stackoverflow. Thanks for your help by the way